# AEM Mockito Junit 5 unable to cover catch block

Tags: mockito, aem, junit5

How do I cover the catch block for for the methods that return void in junit5 and mockito.

below mentioned dump method return void and throws RepositoryException and JSONException.

tidyJosnItemWrite.dump(node, stringWriter, -1);

Answer (score 1):

You need to write new test case like below.

```
@Test
void testGetJson {      

    doThrow(new RepositoryException()).when(tidayJsonItemWriter).dump(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
            
    ctx.addModelsForClasses(Aem.class);
    ctx.getJson(node, tidyJosnItemWriter);
}
```

Comment: not working, as is ask to throw exception at method signature, and after throwing the exception, another error is coming "void type not required here"

Comment: What is the return type of the `dump` method?

Comment: return type is void.

Comment: I have updated answer as for the void method mocking is different

Comment: Now getting the Null pointer exception at doThrow line  with a message "Misplaced or misused argument mismatcher detected here"